# Two-Point Correlator "Standard Decomposition"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, correlation-functions

In the literature, e.g. $\tau$-decays, the two-point correlator is often so called *standard* decomposed into

\begin{equation}
  \Pi_{\mu\nu}(p)^{V/A} = (p_\mu p_\nu - g_{\mu\nu} p^2) \Pi^{(1)}_{V/A} (p^2) + p_\mu p_\nu \Pi^{(0)}_{V/A}(p^2).
\end{equation}

I know from a Lorentz decompostion how get to

\begin{equation}
  \Pi_{\mu\nu}(p) = (p_\mu p_\nu - g_{\mu\nu} p^2) \Pi_{V/A} (p^2).
\end{equation}

My question is therefore:

**Shouldn't there be another spin zero term of the form
 $-g_{\mu\nu} p^2 \Pi^{(0)}(p^2)$?**

Regarding the *standard* decomposition its contribution is set equal to zero? Why?